# Getting Azure Blob Queues Message from Azure Data Factory Web Activity

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to use Azure Web Activity to get the queues message from Azure Blob Storage. The message will then be parsed to obtain the parameter that I need in subsequent part of the data pipeline.

[image]

I am attempting to connect using SAS but keep getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>UnsupportedHttpVerb</Code><Message>The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.
```

What is the problem with the my setting here? I have read through Azure Documentation but cannot seem to find any solution.
Thank you.

Comment: What url are you using? (should be https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages)

Comment: @PeterBons, thank you i added "/messages" and i get successful query but i do not get the message body. can you guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with below URL using SAS and got the expected result.

```
https://<storage_account_name>.queue.core.windows.net/<message_queue_name>/messages<SAS>
```

**This is my Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Web1",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://<storage_account_name>.queue.core.windows.net/<message_queue_name>/messages<SAS>",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "x-ms-date": {
                            "value": "@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'r')}",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

If you check the below checkmark in the queue, you will get the Encrypted message body in the web activity output.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Uncheck it and you can see, I got the message body in the web activity output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. I found out the issue is with base64 encoding.